Asian Floating Strike option call & put
still playing with MC simulations. The behaviour of Asian option as underlying price varies is shown below. Terms: Rate = Fixed Strike, Strike = Floating Strike.
Floating strike means that the strike is the arithmetic average of the underlying asset. So basically the payoff of the Strike (Floating Strike) call would be S(T) - Avg(S) and the other way around for the put.
I do not get why the call price behaves linearly and the put price decreases as the underlying price decreases. I get that the strike is strongly correlated with the underlying asset, but should not the put price curve still be downward sloping?
Many thanks for your thoughts!

